# Loop with Less does not compile right

Tags: css, syntax, while-loop, less

I want to create a dynamic image carousel with less. This is my code:

```
@sides: 9;
.loop(@sides);

.loop (@index) when (@index > 0) {
    #carousel figure:nth-child(@{index}){
        transform: rotateY((360/@sides*@index));
     }

     .loop((@index - 1));
}
```

I debugged it in this [editor](http://leafo.net/lessphp/editor.html#%0A%40sides%3A%209%3B%0A.loop%28%40sides%29%3B%0A%0A.loop%20%28%40index%29%20when%20%28%40index%20%3E%200%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%23carousel%20figure%3Anth-child%28%40%7Bindex%7D%29%7B%0A%20%20%20%20transform%3A%20rotateY%28%28360%2F%40sides%2a%40index%29%29%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20.loop%28%28%40index%20-%201%29%29%3B%0A%7D%0A). You can see the output there.

If I use that working code in my project, which uses client based LESS that is included via Javascript, it does not work:

```
Syntax Error on line 36
http://placeholder.com/css/style.less on line 36, column 21:

.loop (@index) when (@index > 0) {

    #carousel figure:nth-child(@{index}){
```

Do I really need Less installed on the Server or is my syntax wrong?

Greetings
Rene

..

..

** UPDATE **

Firebug displays the following compiled css after I updated to v1.7:

```
 #carousel figure:nth-child(7) {
 }
```

The transform is still missing... if i write

```
 #carousel figure:nth-child(@{index}){
     background:blue;
   }
```

anything compiles correctly.. I'm getting closer, but the problem is still unsolved :)

...
...

** UPDATE 2 **

```
 .loop(@sides);

 .loop (@index) when (@index > 0) {
   #carousel figure:nth-child(@{index}){
   @rotation = 360/@sides*@index;
     -webkit-transform: rotateY((@rotation)+deg);
     -moz-transform: rotateY((@rotation)+deg);
     -o-transform: rotateY((@rotation)+deg);
     transform: rotateY((@rotation)+deg);
   }
   .loop((@index - 1));
 }
```

After recognizing that the deg unit was missing, the editor gives the correct output: [click here](http://leafo.net/lessphp/editor.html#@sides%3a%209;%0A.loop%28@sides%29;%0A%0A.loop%20%28@index%29%20when%20%28@index%20%3E%200%29%20%7B%0A%20%20#carousel%20figure%3anth-child%28@%7Bindex%7D%29%7B%0A%20%20%20%20@rotation%20=%20360/@sides%2a@index;%0A%20%20%20%20-webkit-transform%3a%20rotateY%28%28@rotation%29+deg%29;%0A%20%20%20%20-moz-transform%3a%20rotateY%28%28@rotation%29+deg%29;%0A%20%20%20%20-o-transform%3a%20rotateY%28%28@rotation%29+deg%29;%0A%20%20%20%20transform%3a%20rotateY%28%28@rotation%29+deg%29;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20.loop%28%28@index%20-%201%29%29;%0A%7D%0A).

But my html file gives me an parseError which I dont really understand:

```
 ParseError: Unrecognised input

 in style.less on line 37, column 7:

 .loop (@index) when (@index > 0) {

  figure:nth-child(@{index}){
```

Comment: Do you know which version of the client side JS compiler you are using? Some of the LESS code you are using will not working in older versions of LESS

Comment: v1.1.6 ... I'm going to try 1.7 -- thanks :)

Comment: Are you missing a semicolon after the transform line?

Comment: I fortgot it in the link - thanks! - corrected but no effect :/

Comment: Your code is valid Less and compiles as expected with Less 1.7.0. It's not working just because you're missing the *unit* for the `rotateY` value, e.g. `transform: rotateY(200)` is not valid CSS - should be `transform: rotateY(200deg)`... Thus you need `transform: rotateY((360deg/@sides*@index))` instead. (Actually you could see a warning about this in your browser console).

Comment: See the working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seven_phases_max/g466N/).

Comment: `transform: rotateY((@rotation)+deg);` this is invalid Less syntax. I gave the correct one in my comment above (e.g. `@rotation = (360deg / @sides * @index);` for your code update) I recommend you to stop using  the lessphp demo as Less syntax tester because lessphp is outdated and may mislead you. See http://lesscss.org/usage/#online-less-compilers for alternatives.

Comment: great! that works fine :) thank you also for the link to the compilers

Comment: `@rotation = (360deg / @sides * @index);` - doh! I started to make typos myself. Should be `@rotation: (360deg / @sides * @index);` of course.

Answer (score -1):

LESS requires whitespace between mathematical operators, to reduce ambiguity.

```
transform: rotateY( (360 / @sides * @index ) );
```

That should work.

Comment: "LESS requires whitespace between mathematical operators," - No, it does not.